# Sidebar Sticky div at bottom of viewport

Tags: css, footer, sidebar, sticky

I would like to position a div inside a sidebar at the bottom of the viewport / visible area of the screen. as you can see in the jsfiddle there is a logo div, a navigation div and the sidebar-footer div that should stick to the bottom of the page - but if the screen is too small to display all elements, the navigation should push the footer down.
if i position the footer absolute with bottom: 0 - if the visible area isn't big enough the nav and footer overlap.

```
<div id="left">
<div id="branding">Logo</div>
<div id="navigation">Variable height Navi</div>
<div id="sidebar-footer">Fixed Height, Stuck to bottom Footer</div>
```

the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/marknolan/HvcQW/

the actual implementation:
http://contao.marknolan.ch

any help appriciated!
thanks